# How to use shapeless to abstract a repository client into a generic repository module

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless, path-dependent-type

I'm trying to write a generic repository module that can handle a varying number of keys

```scala
  trait Repo[K, V] {
    def read(key: K): V
  }
```

```scala
trait DynamoDBRepo extends Repo[K,V]{

def aRepo[K:StringIdentifiable,V]() = new Repo[K,V]{

  val dynamoDBClient = ???

  override def read(key: K, tableName: String): V =  { 

  val tableKey: String = implicitly[StringIdentifiable].identify(key)

  dynamoDBClient.Table(tableName).get(tableKey)  //(*)
 }  
}

}

@typeclass trait StringIdentifiable[M] {
  def identify(id: M): String
}
```

(*) However, `dynamoDBClient.Table(tableName).get(key)` can also [take a tuple](https://github.com/scanamo/scanamo/blob/825223cfb72b1884afcd86fa09909ec565affd45/scanamo/src/main/scala/org/scanamo/Table.scala#L62) as a key (partition key and sort key).

Therefore, I want to somehow extract String from K or (String, String) from (K,K) from key:K `override def read(key: K)`

I first tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991061/how-to-extract-types-from-a-tuple-that-implements-a-typeclass) to extract types from a tuple that implements a StringIdentifiable typeclass. I got stuck.

[Then tried to rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044126/how-to-create-an-instances-for-typeclass-with-dependent-type-using-shapeless) a StringIdentifiable type class, that would return String when the argument was one key but (String, String) when the argument to the read was a tuple. But I was not able [to use this method either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046802/how-to-use-a-path-dependent-type-class).

How can I solve his problem without losing my abstraction

Comment: Well, in such case I would simply create a wrapper that would use ADT: `sealed trait RepoKey; case class SimpleKey(key: String) extends RepoKey; case class PartitionedKey(partition: String, key: String) extends RepoKey`. If there are only 2 cases any further generalization is just overengeenering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If requirements from the question are all requirements that you solution must fulfill, then shapeless, path-dependent types and type classes are not necessary at all.

```
sealed trait RepoKey[K] // TBH I am not sure if genericness here is even needed in your case...
case class SimpleKey(key: K) extends RepoKey[K]
case class PartitionedKey(partition: K, key: K) extends RepoKey[K]

trait Repo[K, V] {
  def read(key: RepoKey[K]): V
}

class DynamoDBRepo(dynamoDBClient: ...) extends Repo[String, V] {

  def read(key: RepoKey[String]): V = key match { 
    case SimpleKey(key)                 => ...
    case PartitionedKey(partition, key) => ...
  }
}
```

Even if you store your key as something else than `String`, the only typeclass you would need, would be something like:

```
trait KeyExtractor[K] {
  def extract(key: RepoKey[K]): String
}
```

which almost certainly wouldn't need derivation, but one explicit definition.